# How to using SQL get row count that does have equal values?

Tags: sql, select, grouping

I have a table with columns: id and created(datetime)

```
id  created
6   2011-11-04 20:32:09.673
5   2011-11-04 20:32:09.673
4   2011-11-04 20:29:55.000
3   2011-11-04 20:29:55.000
```

How to write sql, that will return counts of records that haven't, have 2 or have more than 2 equal creation dates. It can be 3 separate sqls.

Thank you

Comment: Not quite understanding your question...  Do you want all IDs to show where the exact same created date/time appears more than once?  As in the subset of records you are showing do not show IDs 1 & 2 because they each have a different date/time and are not the same as each other?

Comment: OR.. are you asking for... of the X number of entries, you want the count that DO NOT have a duplicated create date/time value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe this should do the trick, returning any creation dates that occur more than once.

This one will get those with more than 2.

```
SELECT
    created
    ,COUNT(*) as [occurrences]
FROM
    tableName
GROUP BY
    created HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Swap the > 2 for an = 2 to get those with 2 exactly and =1 to get those with only 1 occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select case reccount
           when 1 then 'No matches'
           when 2 then 'Exactly 2 matches'
           else 'More than 2 matches'
       end as number_of_matches,
       count(*) as distinct_dates,
       sum(reccount) as record_count
from (select created,
             count(*) reccount
      from mytable
      group by created) v
group by
case reccount
           when 1 then 'No matches'
           when 2 then 'Exactly 2 matches'
           else 'More than 2 matches'
       end
```